# Navigation bar Height is not changed in ViewDidLoad() programmatically?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Hi I have tried to change the `UINavigationBar` height progrmatically it has not changed in `viewDidLoad`. but its working `viewDidAppear()` but once I have do my application in background after if open the app it has not changed it going default height.please any one help. thanks advance.

```
  let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
   self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 66)
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `UINavigationBar` extension with your `viewcontroller`

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 80.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes Its working. But still while open it come after that it changed.

Comment: What you mean ? please elaborate more .

Comment: after open backgrond app few seconds after only changed. it getting few seconds delay.

Comment: @vara use code in only `UINavigationController ` see EDITED answer

Comment: But I need in UIViewcontroller itself. please any way is there? @Jack

Comment: @vara i have update answer write it at your view controller